# Parent div collapsing issue. using jquery cycle with 1140 gs

Tags: jquery, css, cycle

Im trying to do an image slider.
with this markup

```
<div class="item-display-col fivecol">

            <ul>
                <li><img src="img/man1.jpg" alt="image" class="item-display"></li>
                <li><img src="img/man2.jpg" alt="image" class="item-display"></li>
            </ul>

    </div><!-- / -->
```

it displays fine, but when i put this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('div.item-display-col ul').cycle({
            continuous: 1,
        });
```

(closing brackets deliberately truncated)

the parent ul collapses into 0 height and the content hangs out of it.

im sure its simple css logic, but i'm not having any luck with putting clear divs and setting overflows.

the only css in play here is the li and img is set to 100% width to span the width of the column

a recreation of the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/nPFkn

Comment: 1140 includes a reset and some other styles that may be important. I don't suppose you have a live instance that we could poke around at?

Comment: tried giving the child element an explicit height, no luck

Comment: @GregPettit no i, wish i had. its on localhost. it displays fine without the cycle.js code though. i edited the code and used <img> tag inside a <div>, same problem. i was thinking the cycle floated my child elements, thus collapsing the parent, but the 1140 already applies a float to my parent div.

Comment: i tried another slider (easy slider) with the same results

Comment: I believe the problem is: i wanted the parent div to be elastic, so i didint set a height; yet the jquery cycle made the children absolute positioned, pulling it out of the flow. i dont think theres a solution to that is there?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned already that you had tried "setting overflows" but without specifics about exactly what you tried. So by way of making a guess: try adding "overflow: hidden" to the ul. This should force the element to have layout. No slider present, but when I did this in a fiddle, the ul stopped being collapsed (the little bit of red peeking through is the UL):

http://jsfiddle.net/SKYJY/1/

Comment: by that i meant i tried everything, visible auto hidden & scroll, just for the sake of being thorough.

i have no trouble with the code without the slider;

here is an example with the slider on [http://jsfiddle.net/nPFkn/](http://jsfiddle.net/nPFkn/); check the source code and you'll the divs are collapsed.

individually the slider and 1140 gs works fine, i cant get them to work together